# Dynamic Pivot table, how to remove NULL values without knowing column names?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Ok, so I got myself needing a dynamic pivot table, and that was fine.

I needed to create a dynamically sized temporary table to hold these values, eventually I worked that one out. Called it #table

Can I get rid of nulls after the insert without doing it dynamically?  I really don't want even more horrific red stuff.

```
#table 

Year   CashflowID1   CashflowID2   CashflowID3........CashflowIDn   
 1      NULL          -4            1.23............... etc
 2      43            78            -34 ............... NULL
```

Each cashflow id might have data for a different set of years, resulting in a bunch of nulls.

Something simple like

```
SELECT ISNULL(*,0) 
FROM   #table
```

but, you know, that is clever and actually works.  As an aside I tried setting up #table with default values and non nullable columns but that just broke the insert.

Shout if I have missed anything obvious, or failed to provide necessary info.

Cheers.

Comment: In general I would say do it during the insert - care to show us the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, this gets a little messy, but here's the idea

For this i'm querying out of the master table and pivoting on a variate of received (datetime).

```
declare @columns varchar(max)
declare @columnsisnull varchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT  @columns = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT '],[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), m1.received, 120)
          FROM master m1 where m1.received between DATEADD(year, -1, getdate()) and GETDATE()
   ORDER BY  '],[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), m1.received, 120) desc
   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') + ']'

    SELECT  @columnsisnull = STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT ', isnull([' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), m1.received, 120) + '],0)'

          FROM master m1 where m1.received between DATEADD(year, -1, getdate()) and GETDATE()
   --ORDER BY  ', isnull([' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), m1.received, 120) + '],0)'
   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
```

this looks basically like your code for getting the cols, with the difference being the @columnsisnull where i just append the isnull function into the columns

then for your @sql

```
set @sql = N'SELECT name, ' + @columnsisnull + ' from master ) p
pivot(sum(amount) for received in ( '+@columns+')) as pvt'

execute(@sql)
```

Comment: Yar, this works and can have an answer.  I had the same @columns thing already for the pivot, adding the second is a neat solution.

  I do not see what the point of 'TOP 100 PERCENT' is in the query, would love to hear an explanation.

Many thanks

Comment: tbh, I don't see a point in the top 100% myself, however when i learned how to do Dynamic Pivots originally this was how I was taught so its carried over since then

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to make one more attempt with default values, this feature should work fine for your case. It is more sophisticated solution since you will not depend on logic in your query and will not duplicate replacement with NULL.